# generate and save multiple pdf files using mPDF

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf, codeigniter-3, mpdf

I have a code to generate single PDF file using mPDF library. But when I try to generate 2 pdf at a time and try to download those files it does not generate second file.

Here is code:

```
function download($id)
    {
        $this->load->library('m_pdf');

        // download annexC form
        $this->annexc($id);

        // download resident form
        $this->resident($id);
    }

function annexc($id)
    {
        $data1['udata'] = $this->general_model->getUserDetail($id);
        // mprd($data);
        $name1 = str_replace(' ', "-", strtolower($data1['name']));
        $time1 = time();
        $file_name1 = $name1.$time1.$id.'-Annexc-Form';
        $html1 = $this->load->view('annexc/form_download', $data1, true);
        $pdfFilePath1 = SAVE_PDF_ANNEXC.$file_name1.".pdf";
        $this->m_pdf->pdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
        $this->m_pdf->pdf->WriteHTML($html1);
        $this->m_pdf->pdf->Output(SAVE_PDF_ANNEXC.$file_name1.".pdf", "F");
    }

    function resident($id)
    {
        $data['udata'] = $this->general_model->getUserDetail($id);
        $name = str_replace(' ', "-", strtolower($data['name']));
        $time = time();
        $file_name = $name.$time.$id.'-Residential-Form';
        $html = $this->load->view('resident/form_download', $data, true);
        $file_name = trim($file_name);
        $pdfFilePath = SAVE_PDF_RESIDENT.$file_name.".pdf";
        $this->m_pdf->pdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
        $this->m_pdf->pdf->defaultfooterfontstyle='';
        $this->m_pdf->pdf->defaultfooterfontsize=12;
        $this->m_pdf->pdf->defaultfooterline=0;
        $this->m_pdf->pdf->setFooter('{PAGENO}');
        $this->m_pdf->pdf->WriteHTML($html);
        $this->m_pdf->pdf->Output($pdfFilePath, "F");
    }
```

When I call download(), then it will create annexc pdf successfully but for second resident() it will create the pdf which has data same as annexc form. Why so? What should I make the changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here is the answer after googling:**

***unset the old HTML and mpdf object and create new one.***

```
function download($id)
    {
        $data['udata'] = $this->general_model->getUserDetail($id);
        $time = time();
        ini_set('memory_limit','256M');
        $file_name_res = $time.$id.'-resident-form';
        $html = $this->load->view('resident/form_download', $data, true);
        $pdfFilePathRes = PDF_FILES.$file_name_res.".pdf";
        $this->load->library('m_pdf');
        $mpdf = new mPDF();
        $mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
        $mpdf->defaultfooterfontstyle='';
        $mpdf->defaultfooterfontsize=12;
        $mpdf->defaultfooterline=0;
        $mpdf->setFooter('{PAGENO}');

        $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
        $mpdf->Output($pdfFilePathRes, "F");

        unset($mpdf); // this is the magic
        unset($html); // this is the magic

        ini_set('memory_limit','256M');
        $file_name = $time.$id.'-annexc-form';
        $html = $this->load->view('annexc/form_download', $data, true);
        $pdfFilePath = PDF_FILES.$file_name.".pdf";
        $this->load->library('m_pdf');
        $mpdf = new mPDF();
        $mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');
        $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
        $mpdf->Output($pdfFilePath, "F");        
    }
```

Comment: Perfect solution!  great

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the same model function

```
$data['udata'] = $this->general_model->getUserDetail($id);
```

And then echoing the same result but with different name

```
$html1 = $this->load->view('annexc/form_download', $data1, true);
$html = $this->load->view('resident/form_download', $data, true);
```

Even if the views are styled different you will get the same result on both.

Comment: so what can be the solution? should I call it once?